# Python C API and global variables modified in python functions

Tags: python

I'm facing a problem that I'm not able to understand. I'm using the Python C API in order to use some Python code in a C++ application.

Basically, I have a python module (MyModule.py) with this stuff:

```
  TheValue=25
  def modifyValue():
      global TheValue
      TheValue=50
```

Then, from the C++ code, I have this:

```
  ...
  PyRun_SimpleStringFlags ("from MyModule import *", NULL);
  ...
  PyRun_SimpleStringFlags ("modifyValue()", NULL);
  PyRun_SimpleStringFlags ("print(TheValue)", NULL);
  ...
```

So, I expected that "TheValue" had a final value of 50, because of the global scope defined in the python code. However, I'm getting always the original value: 25.
It seems that global scope is not preserved when I'm running Python functions from C++ through the PyRun_SimpleStringFlags() function.

I tried also the PyObject_CallFunction() and behavior is the same.

Of course, if I run the Python code from a python console, then TheValue has the correct value: 50.

What's wrong here?
Does anyone have an explanation for this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each module has its own global variable environment, which is the `__dict__` of the module.  The code in MyModule is setting MyModule's `TheValue`, which does not affect the value of `TheValue` that you previously imported into the current module (which is probably `__main__`).  If you re-imported the value, or had done `import MyModule` and were examining `MyModule.TheValue`, you would see the changed value.